# WPA2 AES connection incredibly slow on new samsung laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, encryption, internet-connection

I bought a new Samsung laptop a couple days ago, and have been struggling with my wifi connection ever since.

I believe the problem arises after I install Windows updates from my laptop's factory settings.

Connecting to my Netgear router with WPA2 AES encryption makes for incredibly slow internet browsing, however using WPA TKIP *seems* to be ok.

I'm not a hardware guy, so what I wanted to ask is should I just leave in on WPA TKIP, or should I be trying to get this work properly using WPA2 AES?

I thought I read somewhere that WPA TKIP is limiting.

Comment: Why not roll back the network drivers?

Comment: @RandolphWest I just checked my wireless card's device properties. The rollback option is greyed out, so I guess theres nothing to rollback to. Does that mean the Windows update can be ruled out as the problem, or could it have affected it in another way?

Comment: If there's no rollback option, it's unlikely that the NIC was updated by Windows Updates. Perhaps what's needed is a new driver from the manufacturer's site?

Comment: @RandolphWest Yeah i'm currently checking that out. Checking a site I used before to scan my hardware for new drivers, listed one for my wireless card, so I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing official drivers from [Intel's driver download section](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/default.aspx?iid=subhdr%20dnlds_drivers) fixed my problem.

Feel kind of stupid having had trouble for this long for a mere driver download, but the device properties told me I was up to date so I won't trust it as much anymore.

If anyone is interested, [this is the site I used to scan my laptop for new drivers](http://www.touslesdrivers.com/), it's in french though, but always worked great for me.